# Case (in)sensitive comparison with VB.NET LIKE operator in runtime (without Option Compare)

Tags: vb.net, comparison, case-sensitive, vb-like-operator

Is there anyway to use LIKE operator in VB.NET as case sensitive or insensitive during runtime? For example use a flag to do case sensitive or insensitive comparisons.

Obviously this can be done by simple converting them into lower case and forcing application to `Option Compare Binary` but maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. However, you should probably not use the `Like` operator anyways if case-insensitivity is important - instead, use regular expressions.

```
Dim re As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^.+ough$", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

re.IsMatch("rough") ' True
re.IsMatch("tough") ' True
re.IsMatch("rOUGH") ' True
re.IsMatch("ough")  ' False
```

There's a lot to learn, but basically `.` is equivalent to `?`, `.*` is equivalent to `*`, and `\d` is equivalent to `#`. You have to wrap it in `^` and `$` for equivalency, too. Regular expressions are much more powerful and will do what you need.

You should probably add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` if you plan to use them a lot. They can be compiled and reused for efficiency, too.

Comment: That's the problem I don't need much powerful, I need less powerful :)

Comment: @dr. evil: Can you give us an example of the pattern in question, and in what situation it will be used?

Comment: It'll be entered by user as normal users can't write regex it'll be quite dirty to convert their wildcards into regex, still doable though.

Comment: @dr. evil: Not really; I found an article online that talks about using Like in C#, and you can apply the same principles. Just make the replacements of `*`, `?`, and `#`, escape the whole thing, and surround it in `^` and `$`. It does sound complicated, but here's a pre-made one for you (and if you can't read C#, there's an online conversion tool too): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/bce145b8-95d4-4be4-8b07-e8adee7286f1/

Comment: @minitech Yes that's the approach but I guess you also know that LIKE syntax is not just * and ?

Comment: @dr. evil: Yes, but the other types are equivalent to regex, e.g. `[aeiou]` in `Like` is equivalent to `[aeiou]` in regex.

Comment: Oh. Well, add exceptions: `.Replace("\[", "[").Replace("\]", "]").Replace("!", "^")`

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a custom class to ensure that you get case case-insensitive comparison even if the default settings is `Compare Binary`(case sensitive). You can specify the `Option Compare` in a code-file:

```
Option Compare Text

Public Class CaseInsensitiveLikeOperator
    Public Shared Function IsLike(str As String, pattern As String) As Boolean
        Return str Like pattern
    End Function
End Class
```

Now this works:

```
Dim isSame = CaseInsensitiveLikeOperator.IsLike("foo", "Fo?") ' True
```

If your default is `Option Compare Text` you could provide two classes to be on  the safe side.

Maybe the best option is to learn regex ;-)